# How to update Mac OS X Mavericks desktop background from a script

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

How can I update Mac OS X Mavericks desktop background from a script?

[Update Mac OS X desktop background from a script](https://superuser.com/questions/34054/update-mac-os-x-desktop-background-from-a-script) worked up to OS X 10.8, but doesn't work anymore. The desktop defaults to the default "Wave" background.

Answer (score 7):

The document Jan-Yves referenced appears to be toast now.

I use SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.app on Mavericks. It's a little old but still works.

If you open up ~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppictures.db, you can view the crucial "data" table. It's basically just a path to whatever the current desktop pic should be. **However there can be multiple rows depending on how many monitors you are running.** Apparently you can set different desktop pics per monitor and this improvement is part of Mavericks I believe.

You could manually alter the row(s) in your sqlite editor and then do a 'killall Dock' as long as you remember to save your changes in the editor. That's not really any easier than popping open System Prefs but I tried it out just to ensure how the system worked. Probably makes sense to do a backup of your .db file before manually editing.

Anyway, I use a couple small shell scripts to change my desktop as a warning for when I've altered the hosts file.

The full script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '/Users/user/Documents/My Pictures/dlanham_Phobos.sitechange.jpg'";
killall Dock;
```

You could add an argument easily to allow more control over the picture but this is the basic logic.

You'll see some posts recommend an extra "where rowid=1". For my purposes, I allow the desktop to be changed for all monitors so I leave out the rowid. It'll update multiple rows.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Mavericks has changed where it stores desktop background information. It used to be in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` (as a binary plist file) and it's now in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppictures.db` (as an SQLite file). If you open it up  (I think sqlite3 comes as standard with OS X? Otherwise you should be able to find a SQLite DB app - I use [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/) but there may be nicer out there) you'll notice that you have desktop background file names in the `data` table. The other tables are interesting, but a bit more cryptic. You can basically run an UPDATE query on the table to change the desktop background of a given space, e.g.:

```
UPDATE data SET value=~/Pictures/foo.png WHERE ROWID=1
```

I only just worked this out myself: a little more detail is available [here](http://1klb.com/posts/2013/11/02/desktop-background-on-os-x-109-mavericks/).

[ETA: Fixed link]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the somewhat deprecated appscript to work anymore, so I switched to PyObjc.

Using python 2.7 from Macports with the py27-pyobjc-cocoa package installed:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python2.7

from AppKit import NSWorkspace, NSScreen
from Foundation import NSURL

def change_desktop_background(file, desk_id):
    file_url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(file)
    ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
    screen = NSScreen.screens()[desk_id]
    ws.setDesktopImageURL_forScreen_options_error_(file_url, screen, {}, None)

# Change my second screen desktop
change_desktop_background("myfile.jpg", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get this working myself on osx Yosemite, and through a combo of @yelling_monster answer and the [old bash script](http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/how-to-set-one-wallpaper-for-all-os-x-desktop-spaces-at-once/) that used to work on mountain lion, I made this:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -n "Drag and drop an image file here and hit 'return' (or ctrl-c to cancel)
"
 read -e WLPR;
function change_wallpaper
 {
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '$WLPR'";
killall Dock;
 }
 change_wallpaper
```

Backup your `desktoppicture.db` with a simple

```
cp ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db{,-bkp}
```

Follow the instructions on the site I linked to make the script executable (call it something nicer like `wpset`) and you're good to go.

Once executed, you can still individually change a monitor's background via `Desktop & screensaver` in system preferences, this is handy for a second monitor (the old right-click picture in finder -> services context menu doesn't seem to do anything though)